# Why Dev express ReportService Saves classes but loads byte array?

Tags: devexpress, report

When creating a report designer if a ReportStorageWebExtension is created, it has 2 set data methods and 1 method to get data.

```
Public Overrides Function GetData(ByVal url As String) As Byte()
    ' Returns report layout data stored in a Report Storage using the specified URL. 
    ' This method is called only for valid URLs after the IsValidUrl method is called.

    Return MyBase.GetData(url)
End Function

  Public Overrides Sub SetData(ByVal report As XtraReport, ByVal url As String)
    ' Stores the specified report to a Report Storage using the specified URL. 
    ' This method is called only after the IsValidUrl and CanSetData methods are called.

    MyBase.SetData(report, url)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function SetNewData(ByVal report As XtraReport, ByVal defaultUrl As String) As String
    ' Stores the specified report using a new URL. 
    ' The IsValidUrl and CanSetData methods are never called before this method. 
    ' You can validate and correct the specified URL directly in the SetNewData method implementation 
    ' and return the resulting URL used to save a report in your storage.

    Return MyBase.SetNewData(report, defaultUrl)
End Function
```

Why does set data get a `XtraReport` but getting the data as `byte()`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Devexpress team in this [ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T743034/problem-understandig-reporting-component) it is done like that so you can access to the report properties before you save it. and the proper way to save them is as a byte array like this(shown [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/17553/create-end-user-reporting-applications/web-reporting/asp-net-webforms-reporting/end-user-report-designer/api-and-customization/implement-a-report-storage?v=18.1)):

```
Public Overrides Sub SetData(ByVal report As XtraReport, ByVal url As String)
        ' Write a report to the storage under the specified URL.
        Dim row As DataRow = reportsTable.Rows.Find(Integer.Parse(url))
        If row IsNot Nothing Then
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                report.SaveLayoutToXml(ms)
                row("LayoutData") = ms.GetBuffer()
            End Using
            reportsTableAdapter.Update(catalogDataSet)
            catalogDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        End If
    End Sub
```